# Exposing items in a ListBox through an Interface in MVP

Tags: c#, .net, list, interface, mvp

In a `MVP` application my presenter wants to access / Update data in a list box which is on the `View`. And the `Presenter` is talking to the `View` through a interface `IView`. So I'm planing to expose the *items* in the list box through a property as follows. But I have a problem in using a single property in this case.

```
Interface IView
{
    List<string> Permission;
}


class Form : IView
{
    public List<string> Permission
    {
        get { return lstGivenPermissions; } // Casting error
        set { lstGivenPermissions.DataSource = value; }
    }
}
```

So that my `Presenter` should be able to access and update data in list as follows

```
class Presenter
{
    UpdateModelFromView()
    {
        Model.Permission = View.Permission;
    }

UpdateViewFromModel()
    {
        View.Permission = Model.Permission;
    }
}
```

My `Model` would be like this

```
class Model
{
    Ipublic List<string> Permission = new List<string>();
    //
}
```

I know that the above code will not be compiled due to mismatches in datatypes. (Casting errors).

Could you please let me know how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was looking for this...

```
    public List<string> Permission
    {
        get { return lstGivenPermissions.Items.Cast<string>().ToList(); } //
        set { lstGivenPermissions.DataSource = value; }
    }
```

And it solved my problem!!!